# Error when using npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

I've encountered an error when using  npx create-react-app my-app below is my error code:
npm version is 14 and I've tried 12 also but still encountered this error. Disabled my anti-virus alse

```
error C:\Users\Gringo-PC\Documents\vvv\my-app\node_modules\ejs: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./postinstall.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\Gringo-PC\Documents\vvv\my-app\node_modules\ejs
Output:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Gringo-PC\Documents\vvv\my-app\node_modules\ejs\postinstall.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

what can be the problem with this one?

Comment: Try reinstalling ejs in your app, as that seems to be the resource not found: `npm install ejs`

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have any previous/old version of create-react-app installed globally. If you do, can you uninstall that version before running the npx command..

Comment: You can also clean your cache (just in case) - `npm cache clean --force` and then try npx command

Comment: @nishkaush what do u mean? I have other projects created using create-react-app but when I created this day this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I've fix this problem by deleting all npm folders located in AppData\Roaming then reinstall nodejs.